# Run jol-core exception, the exception message is "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)"

Tags: java, jol

I'm struggling with this problem, can I get your help.

Run Environment:

```
Mac Book 10.15.7 

java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)

org.openjdk.jol.jol-core:0.14
```

Run Code:

```java
public class ClassHeader {
}

public class ClassHeaderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Viewing internal object information.
        System.out.println("Before Print...");
        System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(new ClassHeader()).toPrintable());
        System.out.println("After Print...");
    }
}
```

Console output results

```
Before Print...

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

I was just trying to do a simple test and it led to this question, please help me

Comment: After testing I have found the problem and documented it here in the hope that it will help you.
The problem occurs because jol-core is an extension for the OpenJDK and cannot be used on the Oracle Java Development Kit. For this reason I changed the local JDK to OpenJDK and ran the code in question to get the correct result

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer, comments aren't very noticeable. Would be more helpful for people who might see the post

Answer (score 0):

Because the JDK used by IDEA by default is not OpenJDK, just replace the Project SDK with Open JDK